# Find smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains all singletons

Tags: measure-theory

Find smallest $\sigma$-algebra so that it contains sets $\{x\}$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I was thinking of putting 
$ F = \{ A\subset \mathbb{R} : A \text{ is countable or } A^{c}  \text{ is countable}\} $, but while I was proving it, I figured out that maybe that isn't it.

Comment: The smallest one is the set $F$ you told. Because any of the sets in $F$ can be generated by countable unions and complementations of singleton sets $\{x\}$.

Comment: For the record, $\emptyset$ is countable.